CONEXIÓN A SAML DESDE UN AZURE APP SERVICE
Tengo una aplicación web .net que se conecta a un servidor LDAP. Dicha aplicación la tengo instalada en una máquina virtual de AZURE y, también, como APP SERVICE, igualmente, en AZURE.
Tanto en la MV como ejecutándola en local, en mi entorno de desarrollo, se conecta a LDAP sin problema.
Sin embargo, como APP SERVICE da el siguiente error:

Error: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at AzureAppSce.Rutinas.ProbarLDAP(String as_GID, String as_Serv) 


Entiendo que es un problema de configuración de red, pero estoy comparando lo que tiene la MV y lo que tiene el APPSERV y no encuentro ninguna pista.
El error salta en la última línea:

DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();

de.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer;
de.Path = ls_URL;
de.Username = ls_Usu;
de.Password = ls_Ctr;

DirectorySearcher Busc = new DirectorySearcher( de );

Busc.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
Busc.Filter = String.Format("(&((|(objectClass={0})(objectClass!={0}))){1})", ls_NomFiltro, ls_Filtro);

SearchResultCollection Resultados = Busc.FindAll();


¿Alguien tiene idea de qué puede pasar? Imagino que es falta de conectividad de red entre el APPSERV y LDAP, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.
Gracias a todos de antemano.
